# Seeking free Web Processing Service (WPS) client?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, wps, ogc

A number of products seem to be implementing the server side of the OGC Web Processing Service (WPS 1.0.0) and these are listed at the OGC's [Implementations by Specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/resource/products/byspec) page.

Is there a free WPS client software that can be installed on Windows and be ready to connect to a WPS 1.0.0 server from another vendor/team?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QGIS has a plugin that supports WPS 1.0.0.  Just search for "WPS" in the plugin installer.

Open the plugin install, click on the Repositories, click Add 3rd party repositories and then click back on the Plugins tab.

*Note: I can't tell you much about it as I have never had a use case for it.*

Answer (score 1):

52North has an [open source WPS 1.0.0/2.0.0 web client](https://github.com/52North/wps-js-client), available since 2016.